# Can I make my Ajax calls cause an "in-progress" cursor to appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following code:

```
    $("header")
    .on({
        ajaxStart: function () {
            $(this).addClass("ajax-loading");
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ajax-loading");
        }
    });
```

Is there a way that I can change this so that as soon as an Ajax call starts the cursor changes shape to something that would indicate an action is in progress and have the cursor return to the default after the call has stopped?

Comment: The cursor is controlled by the CSS [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor) property. You can set `cursor: wait !important` on the body, or have an overlay over the whole page preventing further actions while you wait for the result, and set the cursor on that.

Comment: @DCoder. You're suggesting !important. Can I do this with jQuery? Can you give an example so I could accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
$("header")
    .on({
        ajaxStart: function () {
            $(this).css( 'cursor', 'progress' );
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            $(this).css( 'cursor', 'default' );
        }
    });
```

makes cursor to a busy animation over header. You may try

```
$("header")
    .on({
        ajaxStart: function () {
            $('body').css( 'cursor', 'progress' );
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            $('body').css( 'cursor', 'default' );
        }
    });
```

makes cursor to a busy animation over whole body.

Comment: Should I attach this to the body? Before I was using the "header" as I wanted to modify the class of header. Really I want to show the progress cursor whenever there's any Ajax at all.

Comment: `$('body').css( 'cursor', 'default' );` makes cursor busy over the whole body and will return to normal only after ajax completes. If you don't want this, make selector specific like `$(this).css` or `$('.selector_class').css` or `$('#selector_id').css`

Comment: What I need is for any ajax event that starts and stops to change the cursor over the whole body. what would be the best way to do that ?

Comment: use `$('body').css( 'cursor', 'progress' );`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `beforeSend` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function() { //function to do whatever you want to do; }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this? Is this better than the ajaxStart and ajaxStop? Thanks.

Comment: Ummm, you need to study the documentation, there you will get all the details. `$.ajax` is for a particular call, `ajaxSetup` is for setting some common parameters for all ensuing requests. So if you want the cursor to change for all requests, instead of adding a `beforeSend: function() { }` for all requests, add it to the `ajaxSetup` function.

Comment: I'm confused about this because I want a global action and I read: Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(), .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup(). Is the way that blasteralfred not a good way? I was thinking to attach that to body.

Comment: Read the documentation for `ajaxSetup`, you will understand it. The purposes of `ajaxStart` and `ajaxSetup` are different. In this case, both will work.