# I want to change the cursor to wait then back to default after the click event happens

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag when click it activates a function to bring in some database. But while the database is loading I would like to show the wait cursor then back to default cursor when the database is loaded.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('*').css("cursor", "progress");
    });
});
```

but what it does is replace the cursor all time when the "a" tag is lcicked

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337419/can-i-make-my-ajax-calls-cause-an-in-progress-cursor-to-appear

Comment: Be more specific: "when click it activates a function to bring in some database"??

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle thank you from that link I was able to answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function completes, you can reset the cursor.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('*').css("cursor", "progress");
        $.get('your api call', function(response){
            // do something with response
            $('*').css("cursor", "auto");
        });
    });
});
```

However, instead of applying the CSS cursor to all elements, you should just do it on the top-level `<html>` element. It should be a lot faster.

```
$('html').css("cursor", "progress");
```